# How can I check which element has been clicked, if the elements have no id? Using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form with two inputs.  When submit is clicked, the following happens:

1. An object with two properties (one for each input) is created.
2. Each object is pushed into an array.
3. A div is created, the object's values are put into the inner HTML of the div.
4. A span is created, and is appended into the div.

When a div's span is clicked, I want that specific div to no longer appear, meaning the object whose values are in the innerHTML of that div should be removed from the array.

How can I know which span was clicked?

Comment: a) just give them an id/class/data-attribute/whatever b) attach different event listeners that know about the respective div by closure variables c) locate the respective element by its relative position in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

In your event listener you can check it with target property in event you get.
`event.target`

Comment: You'll likely want `.currentTarget`, not `.target`

Comment: Consider accepting answer if this solution helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.getElementsByTagName('span') returns a NodeList of DOM Elements. So for starters, you will have to iterate over them and attach a handler to each like this :

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    spans = spans[i];
    // do something to span
    // forexample: spans.onclick = clickHandler;

}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Attach 'onClick' event on div (point number 3).
2. then use this.event.currentTarget (in this case you will get the clicked span  tag/div tag).
3. Then remove the span tag or the parent element using this.remove() method.

Comment: Thanks for the help!